# How do I get just the audio files from the iTunes main library (returned by Scripting Bridge)?

Tags: cocoa, itunes, scripting-bridge

I have quite a simple problem. I want to put the audiofiles into my table view. How do I distinguish them from pdfs and movies, etc?

I get them from iTunes over Scripting Bridge:

```
    iTunesSource *source = [[[self iTunes] sources] objectAtIndex:0];
    iTunesPlaylist *mainPlaylist = [[source libraryPlaylists] objectAtIndex:0] ;
    library_ = [[NSArray arrayWithArray:[mainPlaylist tracks]] retain ] ;
```

This gives me an error saying the class iTunesFileTrack could not be found ( at linking time)
:

```
[track get];
if(![track isKindOfClass:[iTunesFileTrack class]]) {
    DLog1(@"SKIPPING kind: %@", [track kind]);
}
```

I'm sure I'm missing something simple :)

On a related note: Is there a faster way to read the iTunes library? I just advice on loading it from an xml file but that seems unsafe to me. If apple changes anything in the next release I'm screwed.

Thank you

EDIT: With `sdef /Applications/iTunes.app | sdp -fhm --basename iTunes` I can generate the .m file I need to check for the class. But it does not seem to work:

```
[track get];         
if(![[track className] isEqualToString:@"ITunesFileTrack"]) {
    DLog1(@"SKIPPING kind: %@", [track kind]);
    continue;
}
```

Skipps just my streams :P Not the movies. (Even when I add `(track.videoKind != iTunesEVdKNone)`). Even the PDF's are iTunesFileTracks. But the .h states:

```
// a track representing an audio file (MP3, AIFF, etc.)
@interface iTunesFileTrack : iTunesTrack
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use something like this in my code so it should work (`app` is the iTunes `SBApplication`):

1.) First get the library source

```
- (ITunesSource *)librarySource {
  NSArray *sources = [[app sources] get];       
  NSArray *libs = [sources filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate
    predicateWithFormat:@"kind == %i",
    ITunesESrcLibrary]];
  if ([libs count]) {
    return [libs objectAtIndex:0];
  }
  return nil;
}
```

2.) Iterate through the library playlist(s)

```
NSArray *libraryLists = [[[self librarySource] libraryPlaylists] get];
for (ITunesLibraryPlaylist *list in libraryLists) {
  NSArray *listTracks = [[list fileTracks] get];
  for (ITunesTrack *listTrack in listTracks) {
    // do stuff...
  }
  [listTracks release];
}
```

3.) You can check for other track types like so

```
if (track.videoKind != ITunesEVdKNone || track.podcast) {
  // track is not of type music
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I'd like to find only the audio files. Those listTracks are movies, pdfs, etc. Do you know how to just get the audio files?

Comment: That does not seem to work. It does not leave out the videos.

Comment: It works in my app. I use it for the same purpose - to filter out podcasts and movies.

Comment: How do you filter out the pdfs?

Comment: PDFs are no track item anyway.